# Multisite custom user activation emails - html

Tags: plugins, multisite

I have a plugin which has its own register facility. This is on a multisite. I am using a must use plugin to send a custom activation email. This is the activation email which the user has to click in order to activate their account.

I am using the wpmu_signup_user_notification_email hook to catch the email and change the content. This is working, but the email is not html - any html such as header tags and paragraphs and br's are just included in the text.

How can I make this send a html based email.

Thank you

```
function my_signup_user_notification_email($content, $user_login, $user_email, $key, $meta) 
{
    $m = "<h1>Thanks for signing up</h1>";
    $m .= $content;    
    return $m;
}

add_filter('wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'my_signup_user_notification_email', 10, 5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the filter's documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wpmu_signup_user_notification_email/), the `$content` should be formatted for use by `wp_mail()`. In the [`wp_mail()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/), I find this:

> The default charset is based on the charset used on the blog. The charset can be set using the [`wp_mail_charset`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_charset/) filter.

So it appears you need to explicitly allow WordPress to send HTML mail. See the [User Contributed Notes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_content_type/#user-contributed-notes) section of the `wp_mail_charset` filter documentation.

Here's how I'd tackle your question:

```
/**
 * Filter the mail content type.
 */
function wpse360648_set_html_mail_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpse360648_set_html_mail_content_type' );

function wpse360648_user_notification_email( $content, $user_login, $user_email, $key, $meta ) {
    $m = "<h1>Thanks for signing up</h1>";
    $m .= $content;    
    return $m;
}

add_filter('wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'wpse360648_user_notification_email', 10, 5);

// Reset content-type to avoid conflicts -- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpse360648_set_html_mail_content_type' );
```

(based on code by [Helen Hou-Sandi](https://profiles.wordpress.org/helen/))

Comment: Thanks so much. I had to remove the remove_filter though, otherwise it didn't work - I assume because it is being removed before actually sending the email. I hope this doesn't have any negative effects.

Comment: Yeah, that could be the case. If I read [the Trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578) correctly, the issue is that HTML emails, of course, have `<>` characters in them, and that might interfere with URLs being sent in some emails. Looks like there's a fix coming in 5.4, so it hopefully won't be a concern for too long.